# Prolog having trouble with recursion and LPN exercise

Tags: recursion, prolog

I need to do LPN practical 3 of section 3.4: writing a travel/3 rule with which a route can be searched for. ([link](http://lpn.swi-prolog.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse12))

I currently have the following solution:

```
%% Base cases
travel(X,Y, go(X,Y)) :- byCar(X,Y).
travel(X,Y, go(X,Y)) :- byPlane(X,Y).
travel(X,Y, go(X,Y)) :- byTrain(X,Y).

%% Recursive cases
travel(X,Y, go(X,Z,G)) :- travel(X,Z,go(X,Z)), travel(Z,Y,go(Z,Y)).
```

With these rules, it will find a solution, but when handing it in, I keep getting a time limit error, meaning the program tries too many other things first, before figuring out the solution. Is there any way I could speed this up? If so, what in this code could I improve?

Thanks :)

Comment: What is `G` used for in your recursive cases?

Comment: For keeping track of the other go(X,Y) lines. Like can be seen in the link, when I have these rules, and the facts from the link, then inputting `travel(metz,losAngeles,X)` is supposed to return `X = 
go(valmont,metz, go(metz,paris, go(paris,losAngeles)))`

Comment: Defining `travel(X, Y, go(X,Z,G))` is going to give you trouble since all of your other `travel` calls involve `go` with two arguments, not three. And `G` is a singleton variable, so it serves no purpose as written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there, but you have to use `G` (which I named `Rest` here):

```
%% Base cases
travel(X,Y, go(X,Y)) :- byCar(X,Y).
travel(X,Y, go(X,Y)) :- byPlane(X,Y).
travel(X,Y, go(X,Y)) :- byTrain(X,Y).

%% Recursive cases
travel(X,Y, go(X,Z, Rest)):-
    travel(X,Z, go(X,Z)), % you go from X to Z in one step
    travel(Z,Y, Rest).    % you go from Z to Y in any # of steps
```

Example:

```
travel(singapore,raglan,R).

R = go(singapore, auckland, 
       go(auckland, hamilton, 
          go(hamilton, raglan)))
```

From here, doing the 4 is fairly easy, you just have to add the `how`:

```
%% Base cases
travel(X,Y, go(X,Y,car))   :- byCar(X,Y).
travel(X,Y, go(X,Y,plane)) :- byPlane(X,Y).
travel(X,Y, go(X,Y,train)) :- byTrain(X,Y).

%% Recursive cases
travel(X,Y, go(X,Z,Move,Rest)):-
    travel(X,Z, go(X,Z,Move)),
    travel(Z,Y, Rest).
```

Example:

```
travel(singapore,raglan,R).

R = go(singapore, auckland, plane, 
       go(auckland, hamilton, car, 
          go(hamilton, raglan, car)))
```